# When will Stack Exchange begin accepting proposals for non-English sites again?

Tags: support, area-51, localization, company

A proposal for a [Stack Overflow in Arabic](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/124088/stack-overflow) was just closed with a message referring the creator to a [five year old post](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20988/161991) which refers the reader to [another](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20987/161991) post mentioning (from Tim Post ♦) that the creation of new localized Stack Overflow sites in other languages was on hold:

> After Spanish, it's going to be a bit of time before we're ready to take on another language. I can't say precisely how long other than much longer than I'm comfortable asking people to wait, while the Area 51 process itself continues to raise people's expectations.

It's been five years since that post (arguably quite more than "a bit of time"), and I haven't heard anything except that all proposals for non-English Stack Overflow sites have been summarily closed.

What's the status of localized Stack Overflow variants? Is this something that is going to restart soon as the company recovers from the debacle of last year? Is there a specific set of conditions that must be met (e.g. new localization can only happen after all current non-English sites have had less than 2% spam posts for a period of six months, and the company's financial statements must meet the requirements on the following attached rubric....)? Does "a bit of time" actually mean "go away"?

To be clear, I don't currently have [the required community](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27938/161991) to propose a localized, non-English site, and the purpose of this question is not to get help finding such a community. My question is really whether it is even worth it to go out on my own and try to gather a community in preparation for the reopening of localized proposals, or whether Stack Exchange is really telling us that this is unlikely to ever be possible again.

Comment: Nowhere near official - but the localised sites needed dedicated CMs, or at least those who spoke the language, and a fair amount of specific development. Also arabic is a RTL language, which may have challenges of their own. I doubt that in the short term the drive's there.

Comment: Further reading, in part so I have this all in the same place [some of the challenges of non english SO sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270399/135565)  [Something more contemporary talking about running the sites now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315311/feedback-and-initiatives-on-international-sites)

Comment: Nobody has mentioned localized sites in a long time, and as far as I know there are no plans for restarting it. I don't mean that it'll never be restarted, just that I don't believe it's on anyone's radar right now. More like shoved into a storage closet somewhere and forgotten. The fact that Robert bothered to get that text integrated as a *close reason* so he didn't have to keep pasting it as an announcement every time should speak a lot to the seemingly "permanent" nature of not accepting localized sites. I didn't even know it was a close reason until I closed that proposal.

Comment: @animuson Best I can tell, he reworded the old "not currently feasible" close reason. I think, based on the number of disallowed topics, that it's worth changing it to "disallowed topic" so it generally covers all the disallowed topics (blockchains, recommendations, startups, etc.)